# How to construct an array in a class in java and call it?

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am a beginning java programmer and am having some issues with constructing an array in a class and then calling it and using it. So I have a program that has 2 classes. The first is called MyDate and is meant to declare instance variables, a constructor, and then as toString() method. From there I am creating another class called DateArray that creates an array of MyDate with the name of dateArr.

```
package date_array;

class MyDate {
    public int day;
    public String month;
    public int year;

    public MyDate(String month, int day, int year)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return (month + " " + day + " " + year);
    }

    public class DateArray {
        MyDate[] dateArr = new MyDate[4];
        dateArr[0] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[1] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[2] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[3] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDate[] dateArr = new MyDate[4];
        dateArr.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the code I have so far. I am really struggling with building the array in the DateArray class without getting exception errors and such as. I have tried moving things around into main and use different wording but with looking though my notes and many google searches later I am still completely stuck. What I really need help with is creating my array in the DateArray class, and then printing out the desired arrays to the console. Any help would be great. Thank you much!

Comment: You seem to be confused as to what a class is used for.  Remember you can't just execute code inside the body of a class.  Assigning to `dateArr` where you have in `DateArray` is illegal.  Additionally, if your class simply contains an Array, its completely redundant.

Comment: Also, calling toString on an array will only get you the address of the array. Use `Arrays.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd better put the create each of the array instance on the constructor method on your DataArray class. The toString() method will not print out anything, instead, it just return the string values for you. So you should print out the message on the main method. Please see below code as an example:

```
public class DateArray {

   MyDate[] dateArr = new MyDate[4];
   public DateArray(){
        dateArr[0] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[1] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[2] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[3] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
   }
   public String toString()
   {
       String str = "";
       for(int i=0; i<dateArr.length;i++){
            str = str+ dateArry[i].toString();
        }
       return str;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {

          DateArray array = new DateArray();
          System.out.println(array);

    }
```

}

Comment: You should given an explanation of the changes you have made to the OP's code, rather than just posting a wall of uncommented code.

Answer (score 0):

```
package date_array;

import java.utils.Arrays;

class MyDate {
    public int day;
    public String month;
    public int year;

    public MyDate(String month, int day, int year)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return (month + " " + day + " " + year);
    }

    /*public class DateArray {
        MyDate[] dateArr = new MyDate[4];
        dateArr[0] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[1] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[2] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[3] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
    }*/
    // The above code does nothing

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyDate[] dateArr = new MyDate[4];
        dateArr[0] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984); // add these to populate the array, otherwise it will be an array of nulls
        dateArr[1] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[2] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        dateArr[3] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        // dateArr.toString(); This does nothing, but would have also only given you the address of the array anyways and nothing useful
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dateArr)); // print to the console using the Arrays.toString utility. This is a convenience method that iterates through the array and calls toString on each element and also gracefully handles null
    }
}
```

If you must have the class DateArray:

```
package date_array;

import java.utils.Arrays; // import the arrays library

class MyDate {
    public int day;
    public String month;
    public int year;

    public MyDate(String month, int day, int year)
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return (month + " " + day + " " + year);
    }

    public class DateArray {
        private MyDate[] dateArr = new MyDate[4]; // package scoped member array, should probably be private

        DateArray() { // move array initialization into constructor so that it is populated when the class is instantiated
            dateArr[0] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
            dateArr[1] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
            dateArr[2] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
            dateArr[3] = new MyDate("May", 16,1984);
        }

        public String toString() { // override the toString method so that when you just pass it to print it knows how to turn it into a string, otherwise it will just print the address of the object.
            return Arrays.toString(dateArr);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateArray dateArr = new DateArray();
        System.out.println(dateArr); // You can call dateArr.toString, but this is done by the println method internally, so not necessary
    }
}
```

Also, if you aren't allowed to use the `Arrays.toString` method, then you will have to implement a null-safe implementation yourself like the following:

```
public String toString() {
    String toReturn = "[ "; // initialize the string that you will append to
    for (int i = 0; i < dateArr.length; ++i) { // iterate through the array with i being the index
        if (i != 0) // if it isn't the first one
            toReturn += ", "; // insert a separator
        if (dateArr[i] == null)
            toReturn += "NULL"; // append the word null, because the array index is null
        else
            toReturn += dateArr[i]; // append the index's toString
    }
    toReturn += " ]"; // close off the array visualization
    return toReturn;
}
```

***Note:*** The above code should use StringBuilder, but was simplified for the OP. Appending strings in this manner (using +=) will 'polute' the Java String Pool. While the optimizer will attempt to automatically correct this mistake it is not guaranteed.

Comment: You should explain the changed you have made to the code, the OP is clearly not in a place to understand what you've done here.  Help them, not do it for them.

Comment: @LukePark Changes were explained in comments, but will add more.